# Find the subset of observations that excludes missing values for two columns

Tags: r

I have two columns with missing data.

```
Var1    Var2
1445    40
656     NA
NA      NA
607     NA
2098    15
```

I want to compute the correlations between these columns while excluding the observations with missing data. I tried

```
 cor(na.omit(df$Var1),na.omit(df$Var2),method="pearson")
```

But I get

> Error in cor(na.omit(df$Var1), na.omit(df$Var2),  : 
>     incompatible dimensions

I assume this is because rather than taking the intersection of the two variables, I am getting

```
Var1(NA omit)   Var2(NA omit)
1445            40
656             15  
607     
2098
```

and so no correlation can be run because it changes the length of the columns.

How can I omit all observations containing `NA` so the columns are the same length?

Comment: `cor(na.omit(df$Var1),na.omit(df$Var2),method="pearson", use = "pairwise.complete.obs")`

Comment: But you might want to read this: [Pairwise-complete correlation considered dangerous](http://bwlewis.github.io/covar/missing.html).

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen is the same problem present for `use = "complete.obs"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing values can be dealt with using `use` argument. Refer `?cor`

> use    an optional character string giving a method for computing
>   covariances in the presence of missing values. This must be (an
>   abbreviation of) one of the strings "everything", "all.obs",
>   "complete.obs", "na.or.complete", or "pairwise.complete.obs".

```
cor(df1, use = "complete.obs")
#      Var1 Var2
# Var1    1   -1
# Var2   -1    1
```

**Data:**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Var1 = c(1445L, 656L, NA, 607L, 2098L), 
                      ar2 = c(40L, NA, NA, NA, 15L)), 
                 .Names = c("Var1", "Var2"),
                 row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: terrific. i'd seen that `use = "complete.obs"` but couldn't figure out what it was for. that solved it exactly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with replacing the `NA` values of each variable with the mean, then this is one approach:

```
var1[is.na(var1)] <- mean(var1, na.rm=TRUE)
var2[is.na(var2)] <- mean(var2, na.rm=TRUE)
cor(var1, var2, method="pearson")
```

If the percentage of missing values be small, then the results you get for the correlation coefficient (Pearson, Spearman, etc.) should still be reflective of the truth.